# Screen reader in PDF

Tags: pdf, screen-readers

Does anyone use or know about Screen readers in PDF such as *NVDA*?

I wanna figure out some question about screen readers in PDF:

1. What screen reader can read PDFs? I mean, What should I use, If I wanted to create a PDF Reader(for example with C#)?
2. How can I use a special language(Such as Hebrew or Persian) in screen readers? Can I change default language to special language in a screen reader?
3. IF I can change default language, What shall I do?

Answer (score 2):

YMS is kind of correct with his answer.

> 1.What does screen reader support by PDF?

The screen reader that has the most support is JAWS, this is because Freedom Scientific and Adobe have worked extremely close together. NVDA has pretty good support as well. ZoomText has hit or miss support in Adobe Reader, and next to none in Acrobat.

> I mean, What should I use, If I wanted to create a PDF Reader(for example with C#)?

Honestly, don't even try. It took Freedom Scientific roughly 10 years to get JAWS and Acrobat/Reader working together decently.

> 2.How can I use a special language(Such as Hebrew or Persian) in screen readers? Can I change default language to special language in a screen reader?

See my [answer on localising strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260611/what-is-a-correct-approach-to-using-strong-em-tags-when-localising-strings/11265602#11265602), but JAWS does not even support those languages. So I would tag the first page as an image and put an alt of "This PDF is in Hebrew, please return to the main page to get a ___ version." I don't know those languages, so I don't know if it is more practical to provide a straight English version or a romanization of the languages you mentioned.

Comment: @Rayn: Thanks for your guide. Do you know about accessibility tags in PDF? Can it solve my problem?

Comment: Yes i know about them.  What is your problem now?

Comment: Can I use it for Hebrew or Persian language? because of a screen reader can support and speech these languages?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, screen readers and PDF files (in general) do not get along very well. You can however use PDF files specially created to be used with screen readers. See this post for more details: [What are “PDF tags” and why should I care?](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/what-are-pdf-tags-and-why-should-i-care)

For a non-optimal solution, you will need a component that allows unicode text extraction from a PDF file. You will find many questions and answers about [PDF text extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PDF+text+extraction) here in SO.

Answer (score 0):

you could find information on webaim website: http://webaim.org/techniques/acrobat/