# How do you handle inline tags with angular-gettext?

Tags: grunt-angular-gettext

for instance:

```
<div translate>
This is <strong>awesome</strong>
</div>
```

I would like to know if there's a better approach to prevent sending those inlinr tags to the .po file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to avoid putting markup in my localized strings when I can, but sometimes it is unavoidable.

However in the case of `em` and `strong`, they may need to be left in. Check out the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260611/what-is-a-correct-approach-to-using-strong-em-tags-when-localising-strings) and you'll see that in some cases the translator may need to change or remove those tags altogether.

Another case that comes up often is inline links in text. You might consider putting the actual url for the link in a variable and adding a comment not to change the text inside braces.